# Wav loop points in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, wav

I did read that Unity supports wav loop points metadata (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53934779/525873). We have, however, not found any official doc/release notes that confirm this. Loop points (using Wavosaur in my case) appear to still be ignored. We are on Unity 2018.2.17f1.

We know there are other options to make audio clips loop, but using wav loop points would be ideal. Anyone was able to get wav loop points to work in Unity?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I don't think looping other than 'the whole file' is natively supported. You can however achieve it by filling the audio buffer manually (using MonoBehaviour.OnAudioFilterRead )

Please keep in mind that this happens on the managed side so it might be a little bit expensive, especially if you want to do resampling